# TcpClient indy host by name

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, indy, host

How to Connect the device to the server name?

```
IdTcpClient.host := textbox.text;
```

I have found no fault with the device "Socket error #11001 Host not found."

Comment: Which platform are you running your app on? What is the actual value of `textbox.text`? Can you ping that value and get an IP and ping reply back OK?

Comment: computer>computer "ping computer-pc" ping ok 
computer>android "ping android-24d8e31f7215fa1f" not found

Comment: If you can't even ping it, how do you expect to connect to it?  Are you trying to connect to a server that is running on an android device? Is the device connected to your network?

Comment: Yes device connected to the network.So I made ​​IdTcpServer server. And when I am doing android>android "ping android- 24.....1f" not found

Comment: Sounds like you have a network issue, not a code issue.  Check your firewall/router settings, make sure it is not blocking the connections.